# Loading dl-debug.c in gdb / Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, ubuntu, gdb

When I use `gdb xxx`, while loading, this is the result:

```
dl-debug.c:74: No such file or directory. 
dl-debug.c:74: No such file or directory. 
dl-debug.c:74: No such file or directory. 
dl-debug.c:74: No such file or directory. 
dl-debug.c:74: No such file or directory.
```

lots of it, how can I solve it?

I've searched this in the internet, but all the answers are not the resolution.
Some might recommended that `apt-get source glibc` or `apt-get install libc-source`, but NO HELP.

I've tried to find `/usr | grep dl-debug.c`, but, this file is not on my Linux.

Any help?

Comment: Define "NO HELP". It is clear from a Google search that you're missing glibc debug data.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik hi, in my ubuntu system, "Unable to locate package glibc-source", apt-get can't find this package.

Answer (score 6):

I've solved this problem.

Firstly, use "apt-get install eglibc-source" to get the source file, while "glibc-source" is not a valid package.
Secondly, locate your source file .tar.xz (mine is in /usr/src), uncompressed it.
Finally, run gdb, and type "directory /usr/src/glibc-xxx(your location)/elf", and "dl-debug.c" is in this directory.

Also, adding "directory /usr/src/glibc-xxx(your location)/elf" in ~/.gdbinit might help u a lot.

Comment: confirmed this works. My tar was in /usr/src/glibc/ directory.

Comment: This works great! It looks like it is the opposite now though. 'glibc-source' is valid and 'eglibc-source' is not in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

It worked great! The file *~/.gdbinit* didn't exist in my case. I create it with:

```
echo "directory /usr/src/glibc/eglibc-2.11.1/elf" >> ~/.gdbinit
```

Having done this I didn't had to type it in anymore. I tested it with *gdb* and *gdb -tui*.

Maybe this helps also for this bug:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/571356
I am running on Ubuntu 3.13.0-66 with gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)